# how to clone full inheritance tree model

Tags: django, django-models, python-3.5

Normally, if want to clone a model object. It happens as follow:

```
class ModelA():
     field

obj = ModelA.objects.get(id=1)
obj.id = None
obj.save()
```

Here, it will save the clone the object with new id.

But how to clone the full inheritance tree.

```
class ModelA():
     field

class ModelB(ModelA):
     field

obj = ModelA.objects.get(id=1)
```

Now if we do the same, only ModelA will be clone in db, but how to clone Model B also which has same ptr id as obj.

I tried using,

```
obj.ModelB.ptr_id = None
obj.ModelB.save()
```

None works.

Answer (score 1):

It will be done like this.

```
obj.ModelB.id = None
obj.ModelB.ptr_id = None
obj.ModelB.save()
obj.save()
```